# Getting Latitude and Longitude in R with only city, state

Tags: r

I have a vector of cities, and I need the latitude and longitude for each so I can map them using leaflet. I can easily add the state using `paste()` or by going into the excel sheet and manually adding it. I've seen this question answered before, but their solution was either too old and the packages aren't supported on R 4.0, or they wont work because of API keys needed that weren't needed when they answered the question.

[image]

I'm trying to use the the `tidygeocoder` option, but it doesn't give me correct lat and lon and I am not sure why.

```
df <- DF %>%geocode(Cities, method = 'osm', lat = latitude , long = longitude)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to go ahead and add state abbreviation, this should work for you:

```
df <- DF %>%
  geocode(city = Cities, state = st, method = "census")
```

Comment: Of course this assumes your city column is called "Cities" and state column is called 'st'

Comment: I got my code to work, I am pretty sure the city names were just misspelled.